# Storing a MySQL procedure call in an .sql script file, and executing it

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to do as the title says? So in practice, we have our clients with their mysql database set up. I would like to send them an executable with a linked .sql file which stores a procedure, so once they run this script, it shall update their database with the statement inside the script.

I originally could do this just fine by simply using mysql statements like UPDATE and ADD (not stored procedures), storing them inside an sql file, and have my c# app execute each statement, but then I'm not able to use IF ELSE conditions within the sql which I need for my case. Procedure calls allow conditional statements, but I don't see how I can store them in .sql files and have them executed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible. What you want to do in your SQL script is **create** your stored procedure, then execute it (and possibly drop it again at the end of your script).

Here's an example script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spMyProc;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProc()
BEGIN
  /* Do stuff */
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL spMyProc();
DROP PROCEDURE spMyProc;
```

The `DELIMITER` command is used to ensure that the usual statement delimiter `;` can be used within the body of the stored proc, and not delimit statements in the *script*.

I've created a SQL fiddle here to demonstrate, although it doesn't use the delimiter command due to limitations in SQL fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752bf/1/0

Hopefully this should get you on the right track.

Comment: In the time since I posted the question, I had actually thought of and implemented this exact idea. But I had not thought of dropping the procedure at the end, which would be preferable. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, great minds think alike :)  Thanks for the accept!